# java program in eclipse to read text file in command line

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to read a text file in eclipse, I have "run configurations" -> arguments   set in eclipse , but it always says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:  file.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I have put file.txt under the same folder of myclass and in /bin folder

What else I should look into?

Thanks

Comment: Have you set the working or starting directory in the run configuration?  Did you put the file in that directory?

Comment: thanks a lot! that was the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the working or starting directory in the run configuration, then put the file in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the folder of the project, not in bin folder. If you want to see what is the base path of the files, you can print:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read a file from within an Eclipse plugin you are creating, you should treat at as a resource. Check this for an example: http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/07/06/reading-resources-from-plugin/ Hope that helps.